# PyGitHub: Get avatar of user?

Tags: github, github-api, pygithub

How can we get the avatar of a GitHub user using PyGitHub?

[Github.get_user](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github.html?highlight=get_user#github.MainClass.Github.get_user) gives `NamedUser | AuthenticatedUser`, however, neither [NamedUser](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/NamedUser.html#github.NamedUser.NamedUser) nor [AuthenticatedUser](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/AuthenticatedUser.html) have any functions for getting the avatar, as far as I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, there is a `avatar_url` attribute:

```py
def get_avatar_url(g: Github, user: str) -> str:
    return g.get_user(user).avatar_url
```

This isn't mentioned in the documentation of PyGithub, but *it is* mentioned in the documentation of the REST API of GitHub ([link](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/users/users?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-user)), inside the "Default response" panel.